# keyboard does not dismiss after async task in swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, dismiss

I’m doing a searching task using UItextField and I tap search button it should begin async task fo calling web api and also dismiss the keyboard. But keyboard remains there. Here is the code

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   attemptPost { (success) in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
        spinner.stopAnimation(self)
        btnOk.isEnabled = true
        btnCancel.isEnabled = true
    }

     // after this keyboard should dismiss but does not do so
      return true
}

func attemptPost(_ completion:@escaping (Bool)->()) {
    // some code
}
```

I want keyboard to dismiss once we tap search button and async task should also start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must resign the first responder.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

   attemptPost { (success) in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
        spinner.stopAnimation(self)
        btnOk.isEnabled = true
        btnCancel.isEnabled = true
    }

   textField.resignFirstResponder()
      return true
}
```

See the discussion at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate/1619603-textfieldshouldreturn

Comment: thanks it worked !!